# Run VISTA disk check without reboot

Tags: windows, windows-vista, boot, check-disk

I want to perform a surface scan on my harddisks (S-ATA, P-ATA, USB and E-SATA) in windows VISTA. Is it possible to do this without scheduling the scan on next reboot? It takes a lot of time and I would like to be able to use the computer during the scan. I can accept that this might not be possible on the window partition disk, but I cannot see why it shouldn't be possible on other disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as going to the command prompt (with elevation; `start -> search for 'cmd' -> right click -> "run as administrator"`) and typing `chkdsk /x /r D:` (replacing `D:` with the drive you wish to scan.) The `/x` parameter forces a dismount of the drive, and the `/r` parameter forces a surface scan of the drive. Hope that helps!